# Why should CFrameWnd::OnCreate be called by a derived class?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

Various examples show a the OnCreate method of a class derived from CFrameWnd calling the base class's OnCreate method.

Yet a simple program I created appears to make no difference if I don't do this. The window is still displayed. Am I missing something, or is it just good practice?

Be gentle, I'm just a beginner :)

Comment: If the base class function does something you need done, call it. If not, don't.

Comment: IIRC, if you're using MFC's Doc/View/Template architecture, the CFrameWnd::OnCreate creates the view window (by calling CFrameWnd::OnCreateClient). You don't have to call the baseclass method, but you might bet *interesting* results if you don't call it.

Comment: Call the base function if you are not sure what it is doing. Your program may work without it, but there could be traps along the way. If you know exactly what the base function is doing, and you want to completely override, then don't call the base function in that case.

Comment: @jes: That advice doesn't help. MFC is a library, and its documentation covers the *interface*, not the implementation. How would you determine, what a base class implementation does?

Comment: .wrt determine what the base impementation does: set a breakpoint on the call to the base function and hit F5. When the breakpoint is hit, do a Step Into with the debugger, and evaluate the code. MFC source ships with VS, and with latest version is located in a directory similar to : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\atlmfc\src\mfc\